# Change the Courier default font in pst-barcode (or make it embed)

Tags: fonts, pdf, embedding, pst-barcode, barcodes

When I use `\pstbarcode` command from `pst-barcode` package, it print a barcode using Helvetica and Courier as fonts, but this fonts are they are not free are not included in the PDF.

As you can see, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}

\psbarcode{0-00000-000}{includetext}{isbn}

\end{document}
```

I get the following rendering:
[image]

And, as you can see with `pdffonts` tool, the two fonts are not embed in the pdf:

```
% pdffonts main.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
UNUFWV+LMRoman10-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     13  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Standard         no  no  no       8  0
Courier                              Type 1            Standard         no  no  no       9  0
```

## The current state

For the moment, I solve the problem just with Helvetica, usign the `\pstbarcode`’s option `textfont="Liberation Sans"` like this:

```
\psbarcode{0-00000-000}{includetext  textfont="Liberation Sans"}{isbn}
```

Then, the bottom text font is fixed, but the upper one is not, as you can see with `pdffonts`:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XSRAXK+LMRoman10-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     15  0
Courier                              Type 1            Standard         no  no  no       8  0
EZVLBQ+"Liberation                   Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      11  0
```

So, how can I change the default courier font for another one, like CMU Typewriter or Anonymous Pro **and make this font embed in the final pdf** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pst-barcode option `isbntextfont`.

See the reference here:

https://github.com/bwipp/postscriptbarcode/wiki/ISBN

You should use the PostScript font name with these options which this post may help you to identify:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275493

Comment: Yes the solution was just to do `\psbarcode{0-00000-000}{includetext  textfont="Liberation Sans" isbntextfont="Anonymous Pro"}{isbn}`. So, it’s a problem because this option isn’t at all documented in the manual.

Comment: Page 16: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-barcode/doc/pst-barcode-doc.pdf

Comment: The manual is produced automatically from the wiki content.

Comment: Note my edit concerning PS font names.