How to Darken the ISBN in a Pst-Barcode?
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{3-16148-410-0}
    {backgroundcolor=FFFFFF borderleft=15 borderright=15 bordertop=14 borderbottom=10 textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

which produces the output:

QUESTION: How may I darken the ISBN number listed at the top of the barcode? Is there a way to adjust the darkening a little for its delineation below the barcode as well? (I compile the code with xelatex.)
Thank you.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501593 (my opinion: you want to change the font, not the color)

No, I wish to keep the font the same---just darken it.

I can't compile the example.

@egreg I just compiled it again in xelatex and it worked for me.

You can change the font used for the ISBN code. On my system this works; you may need to change the Postscript font name to one you have.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
  \psbarcode{978-3-16148-410-0}{
    backgroundcolor=FFFFFF
    borderleft=15
    borderright=15
    bordertop=14
    borderbottom=10
    textsize=8
    includetext
    height=0.7
    width=1.3125
    isbntextfont=CourierNewPS-BoldMT
  }{isbn}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}


Note that the ISBN number had to be fixed.

The font is already black (dark) but because of anti-aliasing effects, it looks gray to you. I assume you want to make the font bold, so that is seems darker.
Change the Courier default font in pst-barcode (or make it embed) is related but I cannot make ist work since I do not know how to use PostScript font names (see manuel).


Maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/topic/barcode and see if there are easier to use packages.


% LaTeX solution
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{ean13isbn}

\begin{document}

\EANisbn[ISBN=978-80-7340-097-2]

\end{document}



A barcode is first and foremost a machine-readable code. As such, there is hierarchy of concerns that must be addressed, starting with stable rendering of the machine-readable elements (bars and spaces) and ending with the human-readable text. You appear to be focusing on an issue that is likely to be much less significant in your scenario than a distinct issue that I point out below.
Others have said that you can increase the font weight to obtain a darker impression. That's true, but it disguises the real problem that you are encountering: There is insufficient graphical information in your processed output to render the text cleanly, to the point that the font hinting is failing to achieve a satisfying result. This should serve as a warning that at such low resolutions you must exercise precise control over the formation of the bar and space elements of the barcode so that the printed symbol preserves the intended meaning.
Is it the case that the output that you have provided is a screen preview or the final result? If the output is to be maintained in vector format and rendered on a high-resolution device then it is likely that the screen preview is giving you a false impression. Render the preview at the resolution of the final result to get a better impression of whether the barcode is acceptable.
If what you have provided is in fact the final result, or your final result uses a similar low-resolution process, then you have a much more significant issue than "light text"... Lack of grid fitting.
Because you are forcing the barcode to a particular width — presumably without being sympathetic to the resolution of the end device (nor the screen, in this case) — you are getting instability of line widths. The printed bars and spaces cannot be fractions of the fundamental device dot. This means that well-formed images must grow in quantums of the dot pitch with each element being some integer multiple of the smallest mark that can be made on the page.
In your image, one way that this issue is manifested is that the guard bars have different widths. Don't do this! Scanners read symbols by performing edge to edge measurements, so this instability in your symbol will drastically affect readability.
You cannot simply pick a certain width (such as the nominal width for the ISBN application) and then print a well-formed symbol using a device with some arbitrary dot pitch. You must instead select a width for the symbol based on what is an achievable X-dimension (physical width of a narrowest element) using the actual print head that will plot the symbol. At low resolutions you must carefully control the printing process from end to end to ensure that any scaling and anti-aliasing introduced by the workflow do not invalidate your choice of size.
Fix the barcode itself, then worry about the human-readable text.
Refer to this discussion for more detail.
